# ajax loads with cache for the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

There is a table with several rows. each row has a SHOW button to slide down a hidden div . in that div (classname : Content) load second page content with the id of that table via ajax.the problem is : when one of rows clicked it is work correct and second page load inside it.but when another rows clicked for  seconds , that row loads content of previous row then fix. is there a way to clear last data when a row slide Up ?to fix this problem?
here is my code :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).find(':hidden').val())
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
 $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
 content.slideToggle();
 $(".content").load("secondpage.htm?id="+id+"");
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Ajax Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <input type="hidden" value="123" name="id"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p></p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <input type="hidden" value="456" name="id"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p></p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show your ajax call.

Comment: As you are using class selector for showing the content it will trigger all divs with content class. Instead use ID for displaying the content. Use some id attribute on the show div, which you can find when Show is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the div relative to your clicked element

```
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).find(':hidden').val())
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideToggle();
    content.load("secondpage.htm?id="+id+"");
  });
});
```

Comment: i use your previous update and works great. is there a reason to changed your codes?

Comment: Thank you so much !